# Using Serres GAGA to relate sheaf of differentials on a scheme X to the sheaf of holomorphic 1-forms on $X^{an}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

If X is a smooth scheme of finite type over $\mathbb C$ and $\Omega$ is the sheaf of differentials on X. Using Serres GAGA what can be said about the sheaf $\Omega^{an}$, is it the sheaf of holomorphic 1-forms specifically? If not call the sheaf of holomorphic 1-forms $\mathscr F$. Are $\mathscr F$ and $\Omega^{an}$'s sheaf cohomologies isomorphic?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: As $X$ is smooth the $\Omega_X^i$'s are locally free, hence the isomorphism.